# Using toJSON() in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am trying to find out how to properly use the `toJSON()` function in Backbone.js for an online tutorial. The tutorial states:

> If you don't remember how toJSON works, consult the [Backbone Model docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model).

However, when I follow the link and click on toJSON in the left sidebar, it just talks about `JSON.stringify` instead of `toJSON()`. Can someone tell me the correct usage for the `toJSON()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a convenience method - for example when passing a model into a template using `model.toJSON()` will pull out the model attributes from the model object for use by your template. You could as easily pass in `model.attributes` and that would interpolate also... I guess the "toJSON" name means "create a representation of my model attributes as JSON" and not all the other properties a model object has.

Comment: your accepted answer is how `Date.prototype.toJSON()` works and not Backbone's toJSON...

Comment: check the Backbone annotated source to see it clearly in action http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-61

Answer (score 1):

> **toJSON** `model.toJSON([options])`
>
> Return a **shallow copy** of the model's attributes for JSON stringification. This can be used for persistence, serialization, or for augmentation before being sent to the server.

(*emphasis mine*)

The key thing here is that `toJSON` returns a **copy** of `model.attributes`, which can be used for templating and many other things mentioned above. The advantage of using this method is that you can make changes to it without affecting the actual model.

For example suppose you need to transform the data before communicating with the server, such as removing currency separator or something - You can update the copy of data retrieved via `toJSON` and send to server without affecting the actual attributes.

These kinds of situations arise mainly when you are using a data binding library such as [rivetsjs](http://rivetsjs.com/) where the model data is tightly bound to UI. If you remove the currency separator in actual model attributes then it'll reflect in UI - which is not good. Hope that helps to get an idea.